# Doing batch requests in the office 365 email rest api

Tags: c#, rest, office365

I've found [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/dn903506.aspx) that says that the Office 365 REST API supports batch requests.
I have tried to use this to retrieve emails using the Office 365 REST API, but so far I receive a "400 - Bad Request" reply. Does this simply mean that the email part of the API does not support batch requests yet?
In any case the only examples on the web are for Sharepoint I have found nothing about the Office 365 API.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. The Mail API doesn't support batching yet.

Comment: Are there any plans to support this?

Comment: Yes there are, but I don't have a specific timeline.

Comment: Any more news on this? Cant find anything, whould be nice to have!

Comment: No sorry. Watch our blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/) or follow me on Twitter (@JasonJohMSFT) to get updates.